# Sorting According to Given way

Tags: r

Lets say I have a dataframe containing 26 unique values (which may repeat) in one column(A-Z) and some other data in other column:

```
A   data data
B   data data
A   data data 
C   data data    
D   data data
R   data data
T   data data
.
.
Lets say it has total 400 values but only 26 are unique which means some are  
repeating
```

Now lets say I have a dataframe containing say 10 of these unique values and each unique value appears only once like below :

```
A
R
Y
U
.
.
It has only 10 unique values
```

Now How should I select only those rows from first dataframe which contains any one of the unique value from second dataframe i.e all rows containing any of the 10 unique values of second dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%`, it's vectorized. Note that I've used `unique` in the second solution just to show that it is **not** needed.

```
set.seed(1596)
dat <- data.frame(x <- sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE), y = rnorm(50))
select <- data.frame(x <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 20, TRUE))

inx <- dat$x %in% select$x
inx2 <- dat$x %in% unique(select$x)
identical(dat[inx, ], dat[inx2, ])
[1] TRUE
```